# porque aparece en el base del kdiff3 "Temporary merge branch 1"

Tags: git

A veces cuando quiero hacer un merge de mi rama a otra rama en el KDiff3 aparece:

[image: imagen]

Y no sé porque pasa, pero es muy engorroso a la hora de mirar conflictos.
¿cómo puedo quitarlo?

Gracias.

Comment: ¿Podrías decirnos en qué momento te aparece esto? Tiene toda la pinta de que has tratado de resolver algún conflicto de versiones y que tu git ha generado versiones temporales para realizar el `merge`.

Comment: Pues tengo mi rama donde trabajo, y me posiciono sobre la rama de develop para hacer el merge con mi rama, y justo cuando lo hago me indica el Kdiff que tengo conflictos, así que, abro el fichero y me aparecen 3 archivos "Base", "LOCAL" y "REMOTE", en el "BASE" me aparece lo que he indicado en la imagen. Entendía que el "BASE" es la revisión base de "LOCAL" y "REMOTE" pero quizás estoy equivocada.

Comment: ¿Cómo puedo saber si hace conflicto de versiones?

Comment: Vale, en ese contexto tiene más sentido y es lo que me imaginaba. Para comprobar los conflictos se realiza un `merge` temporal con el que obtener las diferencias entre ambas versiones. En la cabecera te debe aparecer con símbolos `>>>>...` y `<<<<...` a qué versión hace referencia cada uno (la tuya, ours, o la suya, theirs). Voy a buscar la definición del formato de `diff3` para que entiendas mejor lo que significa tanto bloque. Edito: Echa un vistazo al punto 7 de https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/08/diff3-examples/

Comment: Reduciendo mucho la explicación: entre los bloques `<<<<<<<` y `>>>>>>>` se explica el contenido de cada conflicto conteniendo primero tu modificación, tras el `|||||||` el contenido original (del padre común de ambas ramas) y tras el `=======` el contenido de la otra rama que entra en conflicto con la tuya.

Comment: Gracias @OscarGarcia por la ayuda. La verdad es que lo he entendido un poco mejor. Es que como a aveces me salía y otras veces no, pensaba que era algo que había hecho mal. Pero al decirme que es un fichero que se genera solo, ya lo entiendo mejor.